# Suspend foreground process with AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I have found how to suspend a specific process, and how to get the process path and name of the foreground window, but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

I found this script and have been testing it with Spotify, and it has been working perfectly so far.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

!s::
Process_Suspend("Spotify.exe")

!r::
Process_Resume("Spotify.exe")
;============================== Working on WinXP+

Process_Suspend(PID_or_Name){

    PID := (InStr(PID_or_Name,".")) ? ProcExist(PID_or_Name) : PID_or_Name

    h:=DllCall("OpenProcess", "uInt", 0x1F0FFF, "Int", 0, "Int", pid)

    If !h   

        Return -1

    DllCall("ntdll.dll\NtSuspendProcess", "Int", h)

    DllCall("CloseHandle", "Int", h)

}



Process_Resume(PID_or_Name){

    PID := (InStr(PID_or_Name,".")) ? ProcExist(PID_or_Name) : PID_or_Name

    h:=DllCall("OpenProcess", "uInt", 0x1F0FFF, "Int", 0, "Int", pid)

    If !h   

        Return -1

    DllCall("ntdll.dll\NtResumeProcess", "Int", h)

    DllCall("CloseHandle", "Int", h)

}



ProcExist(PID_or_Name=""){

    Process, Exist, % (PID_or_Name="") ? DllCall("GetCurrentProcessID") : PID_or_Name

    Return Errorlevel

}
```

I also found this page on getting the current process ID: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm.

Is there a way to put these together and make the suspend script work for any foreground process instead of just the one specified in the script?

Specifically, how does one get the ProcessName or ProcessPath and insert it where "Spotify.exe" currently sits? What would the script for something like that look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the script is working, all you need to do is get the PID of the active
process and call `Process_Suspend`.
You should keep the PID for use when resuming.

Similar to:

```
pid = 0

!s::
WinGet, pid, PID , A ; A means the active window
Process_Suspend(pid)
Return  ; otherwise the script jumbs to the next hotkey and the process resumes

!r:: Process_Resume(pid)
```

Comment: I can confirm this works. In case anyone stumbles onto this (I'm surprised it was this difficult to find an autohotkey script that suspends and resumes the foreground process), just make sure to include that pid = 0 at the top and also include all the code from the '====Working on WinXP+' section. In other words, replace only the "!s:: Process_Suspend("Spotify.exe") !r:: Process_Resume("Spotify.exe")" from the code in my original question with the code provided by harrymc. Many thanks for this answer, this is a great resource saver.